# Community Deployment

Tags: community, change-set, data-migration

I am trying to deploy community from one dev sandbox to another(through change set).
When i am trying to deploy with no community with same name i get:  *This record isn't in the target org: Partners.*
When I create one with same name i get:
*Sorry, this URL is already taken*
On both times I get this: *An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 884736746-116841 (-1362776250)*

Anyone here has done that kind of thing? Is it possible?

Comment: Can you make sure you don't have any communities in the target org with the same name

Comment: As i said on post, When i try to deploy it without having Community with same name i get the following *error:This record isn't in the target org: Partners* @Yaswanth Tikkisetti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please confirm,if you have created the same domain in the Sandbox.For each community, the network component has a unique name and URL path prefix. When you retrieve the network component, the generated XML file name is based on the name of the network.

So,when we deploy the community it overrides the community in destination org.

I would suggest you to go through the considerations and tips to deploy the community.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrate_considerations.htm&type=5

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked in our internal server logs and the actual error message is as below:common.exception.ApiException: Can’t rename the default navigation menu.

In order to fix the issue,we need to clone the changeset(if you are using changeset) and remove the Navigation Set from the component.

Otherwise,you can simply remove the component from the payload for any other metadata tool deployments.Since,the issue is occurring because of the navigation menu which can't be changed.Once,you remove the navigation then try the deployment again.

Comment: Hi Shirisha Pathuri, I updated the change set, as you suggested,which got rid from the unexpected error.  However, I am still getting: _This record isn't in the target org: Partners_ when i change name for community, when i leave the name as partner i get: Sorry, _this URL is already taken_

Comment: Hi Shaked,have you checked the domain name that you have used since it should be same in both orgs.Please vote the below Idea which has been created for this.https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ktizAAA